# How to "Require-bundle" all bundles available in a directory

Tags: bundle, require, osgi-bundle

I want to require-bundle all bundles available in a specific directory. When I tried using * in the require-bundle it complained. It needs a specific symbolic name. Is there a way to require-bundle all bundles available in a specific directory?